# How to add an exmaple to swagger_auto_schema in django rest framework?

Tags: django, swagger-ui

I am working with `@swagger_auto_schema` for documenting APIs in `django-rest-framework`.
I want to add examples for both input and output.
here is my code for one of the APIs.

```
from drf_yasg import openapi
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema
@swagger_auto_schema(
    methods=['post'],
    request_body=openapi.Schema(
        type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT,
        required=['name', 'lastname', 'username', 'password', 'confirm_password'],
        properties={
            'name': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, max_length=50),
            'lastname': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, max_length=50),
            'username': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description="it must be unique for every person. it must not contain space or invalid characters."),
            'password': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
            'confirm_password': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description="password and confirm password must be same"),
            'national_code': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
            'license_code': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
            'birthdate': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, default="yyyy-mm-dd", description="it is actually a date"),
            'gender': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER, enum=[(1, _("Male")),(2, _("Female"))]),
            'address': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
            'email': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
            'phone_number': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
            'image_code': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description="it is the base64 code of the image"),
        },
        # One example for a correct body
    ),
    responses={
        200: 'Staff Created Successfully!', # One example for 200 status code
        400: 'Error!',
    },
    operation_description="Add a new staff API. The role field(=staff), customer field(=parent.customer) and parent would be set automatically",
)
```

And this is the rendered schema in swagger. But I want to add two read only `JSONs` jsut for rendering the correct input and the desired output.
[image]
[image]

I will be grateful for any helpful link or examples.

Comment: The "Example body" is displayed on the "Example Value" tab https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcJIz.png. For the "Expected value" to appear, you need to define the schema for the 200 response, check your framework/library docs to see if it supports this.

Comment: Thanks Helen. I have add an example body by defining `default` values for each parameter. But I have not yet find something for response schema.@Helen